# Batch file CURL String with Spaces and Special Characters

Tags: batch-file, curl

I'm trying to get a string from an url using a batch file.

String example:

```
e-e --ser u.g --p 3 --f 0 x,ss
```

I am using the command below to CURL output directly to a variable:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('curl.exe -s -S %URL%') DO (SET W=%%I)
```

The problem is, when I echo the variable [W] after the command runs, most of the string is missing...

```
e-e
```

What is the best method to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `FOR /F` command delimits the output based on a space and tab. That is stated in the help file.  To keep that from happening use the `DELIMS` option to tell the `FOR` command to not use any delimiters.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('curl.exe -s -S %URL%') DO (SET W=%%I)
```